# Can't cast type int to char using function parameters C++

Tags: c++

Hello im trying to understand why i can't cast type int
To a char using a user defined function with parameters.

Im following along with learncpp. And i am a beginner,
So please could i have the simplified versions.

If i create a user function, And try a return the value back it will just output the integer instead of an ASCII character.

Here is my following code.

```
int ascii(int y)
{
    return static_cast<char>(y);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ascii(5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will not return the printable character `'5'`.

Comment: What would you like to print out, `char` '5' or 5th character in ASCII code table?

Comment: I would like to print out the 5th character in the ASCII table

Comment: @peterevans Then I believe jpr42's answer can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the type of your return value. It should be a `char`. Not an `int`

```
char ascii(int y)
{
    return static_cast<char>(y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you i didn't realise you could use a char return type.